# Amplify cognito auth differing from build and local

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Currently I am creating a full-stack app using Amplify and I have followed the amplify tutorial to this point. I have shifted the auth coginito login to be from username to email but now these changes are not reflected on the amplify build. Both `amplify pull` and `amplify push` have been used and the github repo is also up to date but the changes still differ.

How can I fix this?
Thank you

Build login:
[image: Build Login]

Local login:
[image: Local login]